# Front End vs. Back End vs The Database vs Cloud Functions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, frontend, google-cloud-functions, backend

I am just trying to get a better understanding of the full stack in development and all the different frameworks etc have gotten confusing in my head and I just want to try and wrap my head around everything. The main question is: What are the main differences between the front end, back end, database, and how do things like say Google Cloud Functions fit into all of this?

For instance, ReactJs is a frontend framework (technically library) that helps you build fast and responsive front ends using components. So with reactjs I could create a front-end to a web page with buttons and logic for moving around and showing data.

So in this case when and why would I add on a backend? For processing large amounts of data or running calculations is a good idea but how does this actually fit in? For instance Ruby on Rails uses the MVC framework so if I added Rails to a ReactJS project would the Reactjs part essentially just become the V (view) of the ruby on rails project? How does this compare to node.js and django? Why and when do I even use all of these?

Next, when adding databases into the mix when should I be using the front-end to use the database and when should I use the back end? For instance in a react app I could send and receive data from a firestore nosql database from the frontend but I could also make a ruby on rails app that creates migrations to alter the schema in lets say a postgresql database. So when and why should I be using each method?

Finally, one of my main questions is how do cloud functions fit into all of this? Do cloud functions just take away the "back-end" portion of the equation? I haven't used them but wouldn't you still have to write functions that take an input and spit back an output? Is the only difference with cloud functions that they are easier to maintain since you don't have to set up your own server?

What would common tasks and their differences be between a front-end and back-end developer?

Comment: There's too many open-ended questions here to be a good question on Stack Overflow.  Consider posting to a discussion forum such as Reddit or maybe a Google group, where it's easier to go back and forth with people.

Comment: Good point that would have been a better avenue thanks

Answer (score 0):

The front-end talks to the backend. The backend then talks to the database, and relays info back to the frontend. The cloud is just a place to host your front/backend/database. Front-end developers build the User Interface (buttons, forms, screens, etc). Backend developers build the services that the front-end will push/pull data from, which it typically stores/retrieves from a database.

Comment: Why not just make a frontend where all the data is pulled from a database? I assume the need for calculations is what facilitates a backend or cloud functions

Comment: @FrankTheTank Calculations, and often, security. If the front end has complete access to the database, it can do whatever it wants with the data. Or, more specifically, nefarious users could use it to do what they want with the data. For example, deleting things. In general, you'll have a system where front ends authenticate with your back end and are given a token. The token represents details about them. For example the token could say "I am Bob." Because the token was issued by your back end, your back end would trust it on future requests and process things like changes to the database.